# Error when saving model with django form wizard

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am getting an `IntegrityError` when trying to save my model to the DB

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    new = Business()
    new.user = self.request.user
    for form in form_list:
        for k,v in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            new.k = v
    new.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

The error says: `(1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")`

The form that is being completed and has the category model:

```
class AddForm2(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Category.objects.filter(children__isnull=True))
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = City.objects.all())
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200, label="Business Name")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length = 200, label="Street Address")
    slogan = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    website = forms.URLField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

Business in models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('1','Basic'),
        ('2','Silver'),
        ('3','Platinum'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ad_type = models.CharField(choices = TYPE_CHOICES, default = '1', max_length=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

---

EDIT:

I changed the line `new.k = v` for `setattr(new,k,v)` in my done method and it worked. Not sure what the difference is...

Comment: Show your `Business` definition in your models.py

Comment: By default, fields have `null=False` and `blank=False`. You might want to do that in your `category` field if you want it to be null. Set it to `null=True` and `blank=True`. More info in [Field Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options)

Comment: YOu can also double check with python manage.py sqall to check your tables

Comment: I don't want the category field to be null

Comment: And why are you trying to save a Business model without asigning any category?

Comment: I am not. The category is being selected in the form

Comment: And in which part of your code you are validating the form? Where is your view?

Comment: I figured it out... check edit

Comment: @alexBrand `new.k = v` is equivalent to `setattr(new, "k", v)`, as opposed to `setattr(new, k, v)` - you were assigning to the `"k"` attribute repeatedly, instead of assigning to the attribute whose name is in the `k` variable. `setattr()` is the correct way to do that, so you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

The done() function should use setattr instead:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    new = Business()
    new.user = self.request.user
    for form in form_list:
        for k,v in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            setattr(new, k, v)
    new.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging into `django.forms.models`, I'd suggest using the convenient `construct_instance` method to save data from multiple forms to a single instance:

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.forms.models import construct_instance


class YourFormWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        new = Business()
        new.user = self.request.user
        for form in form_list:
            new = construct_instance(form, new, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        new.save()
        return redirect('/')
```